# How to cast getSource() to be a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

I am making a `KeyListener` class so I can control any `JTextField` that I want, but I do not know how to get whatever `JTextField` I call so I can press escape and clear the `JTextField`? Here is my current code

```
private class IntegerTxtListener implements KeyListener {
    public void keyTyped(final KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyChar() < KeyEvent.VK_0
                    || e.getKeyChar() > KeyEvent.VK_9) {
                e.consume();
            }
        if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
            e.consume();
           //My Problem is Here----------------------------
            e.getSource()).setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this schould work:

```
if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
    e.consume();
   //My Problem is Here----------------------------
    ((JTextField)e.getSource()).setText("");
}
```

Just the default way of casting objects.

**But** it might happen that some errors occur if `e` is not an instance of `JTextField`.
So if you are sure that your Listener will not give a source other than JTextField object you can go this way. Otherwise you you add errorhandling /-prevention.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like, to me, you are trying to create a text field that only allows integer values. First of all, you shouldn't be using a `KeyListener` for a `JTextField`. Instead you should be using a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) for the underlying document of the `JTextField`. The [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) can filter out any unwanted input.

Here is an example of a `JTextField` that only allows integer input.

```
private JTextField createTextField() {
    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    ((AbstractDocument) field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int off, String str, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {
            fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr);  // remove non-digits
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int off, int len, String str, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {
            fb.replace(off, len, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr);  // remove non-digits
        }
    });
    return field;
}
```

---

Also, may be unrelated, but another listener you may want to look into, dealing with text input is a `DocumentListener`, that will listener for changes in the underlying document of the text field. You can read more at [How to write DocumentListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

Comment: +1 for understood what OP try to do, and a better solution :)

Comment: @nachokk I just saw the `IntegerTxtListener` and made an assumption. Who know's I may be wrong.

Comment: @user3502019 then you should accept this answer as correct (with the green mark) and not the one you accept i. guess

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve but if it is about to control user input consider using a `DocumentFilter` instead.

If you still want to use a `KeyListener` just cast  `e.getSource()` to `JTextField`, to ensure to don't have a `ClassCastException` you should use `instanceof` operator like example below.

```
if(evt.getSource() instanceof JTextField){
   JTextField textfield = (JTextField) e.getSource();
   textfield.setText("..");
   e.consume();
}
```

Consider extends `KeyAdapter` rather than implementing `KeyListener`.